# Split the array variable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array like this.

(

2right,
    1,
    3,
    4

)

I want it to separate out right. Like this

(

2,
    1,
    3,
    4

)

I tried out this one but not working.

```
NSMutableArray * array=[self.AnswerDic objectForKey:@"first"];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
optionA.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:0]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:0];
optionB.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:1];
optionC.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:2]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:2];
optionD.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:3]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:3];
```

Give me warning.  How may I separate out the string?

Comment: diwnvoter why downvoting me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
NSMutableArray * array=[self.AnswerDic objectForKey:@"first"];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
optionA.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:0]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:0];
optionB.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:0];
optionC.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:2]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:0];
optionD.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:3]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

There will be only one object when you use:

```
optionB.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:1];
```

So index 1 will cause issues. (for consecutive codes have similar issues). So use:

```
optionB.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray * array=[self.AnswerDic objectForKey:@"first"];
optionA.text=[[[array objectAtIndex:0]componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"]objectAtIndex:0] ;
```

Do like this

Comment: how may ic check for all optionB.Text OptionC.Text it give me error.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it'll help you.

```
NSMutableArray *array=[self.AnswerDic objectForKey:@"first"];
NSMutableArray *FinalArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]];

for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
{
    [FinalArray addObject:[[(NSString *)[array objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"right"] objectAtIndex:0]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", FinalArray);
```